# jQuery: Can I do $("#testA", "testB").slideDown(400);?

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code. Instead of splitting them out into 2 blocks of code, can I combine them? Like $("#nc-eftpos","nc-visadebit")... I have tried it but it is not working? But I am pretty sure I have seen something like that before?

```
   if ($("#nc-eftpos").is(":checked")) {
    $("#q-cards").slideDown(400, "easeOutQuart");
    }

    if ($("#nc-visadebit").is(":checked")) {
    $("#q-cards").slideDown(400, "easeOutQuart");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use multiple selector like

```
if ($("#nc-eftpos, #nc-visadebit").is(":checked")) {
    $("#q-cards").slideDown(400, "easeOutQuart");
}
```

The [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) will return true if atleast one of the elements in the set satisfies the passed selector, so you can create a set containing both the elements using [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: Why not using a class? Then you can easily hook and check all elements with that class name?!

Comment: @lucianandrei nothing, if there is a common class it can be used... since OP has only 2 elements and they had ids we can use it without much mess

Comment: @ArunPJohny True in this case, it's not a big deal for 2 selectors case, but it would be more mantainable and good looking written code.

Comment: @lucianandrei yes.. that will be

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||` operator:

```
if ($("#nc-eftpos").is(":checked") || $("#nc-visadebit").is(":checked") {
     $("#q-cards").slideDown(400, "easeOutQuart");
}
```

or `,` to separate your selector:

```
if ($("#nc-eftpos,#nc-visadebit").is(":checked")) {
    $("#q-cards").slideDown(400, "easeOutQuart");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks more like an OR statement, though it might trigger twice in your current code?

```
if ($("#nc-eftpos").is(":checked") || $("#nc-visadebit").is(":checked")
     $("#q-cards").slideDown(400, "easeOutQuart");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do $(“#testA”, “testB”).slideDown(400);?

Yes, [multiple element selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) is allowed in jQuery.

It is a perfect case for using **class**. As if number of element keep increasing you need to add these to list instead assign the same class to all element you want to slide and use:

```
if ($(".nc-visadebit").is(":checked")) {
    $("#q-cards").slideDown(400, "easeOutQuart");
}
```